# Javascript Simple Addition Tool - NaN

Tags: javascript, nan, performance

I'm trying to make a simple addition tool to add 2 values together, I'm just having a little trouble with the NaN checking... would like to print "Please insert numbers only" if either A or B, or both are NaN.

```
function getTotal() {
var a = parseInt(document.addBoxes.boxA.value);
var b = parseInt(document.addBoxes.boxB.value);
if (total != NaN) {
    total = a+b;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "The sum is " + total + ".";
}
else if (a === NaN || b === NaN){
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Please insert numbers only.";
}
else if (a === NaN && b === NaN){
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Please insert numbers only.";
}
```

};

Also, if there is a performance-friendly way to do this, or a better method.

Thanks!

Comment: [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Checking for a and b equal to NaN is redundant since you already checked if either were NaN

Answer (score 2):

Checking each individual value for `NaN` is not required.

```
function getTotal() {
    var a = parseInt(document.addBoxes.boxA.value);
    var b = parseInt(document.addBoxes.boxB.value);
    var total = a + b;
    if (!isNaN(total)) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "The sum is " + total + ".";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Please insert numbers only.";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do total = a+b before you check if it is NaN

Comment: You still do the total addition twice, no need.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems in your code.

```
Line 4: if (total != NaN) {
```

`total` hasn't been defined yet. You should define it in a `var` beforehand if you don't want to leak globals.

```
var total = a + b;
```

Also, `NaN` will never equal itself so this kind of equality is dangerous. Either use the built-in `isNaN()` function to check for NaN or (since you mentioned performance-friendly) you can skip the function invocation and use:

```
if (total !== total) {
```

Since NaN is the only thing in javascript that doesn't equal itself. Notice I'm using a strict not-equals, we don't want any coercion. This might be a bit too abstract and people who look at the code later (including yourself) might have forgotten this unique property of NaN so I'd prefix this conditional with a comment and perhaps a link to the [MDN - Necessity of isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#The_necessity_of_an_isNaN_function) page.

Your code might end up looking something like [simonzack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25429320/1217408).